# Does anyone know how to change response error format in Spring security oauth2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring security oauth2. By default oauth2 returns it's own error format like `{error : "Invalid_grant", error_description : "something"}`. I want to change it my own custom format so in my application, it remains consistent. Can anyone please help me? I have gone through lots of links but didn't find any suitable solution till now.

Answer (score 0):

What you get as a result is a JSON document.

1. Look at Jackson or Gson libraries for example to parse(deserialize) JSON documents. You can get data values 1 by 1 or deserialize into a class instance.
2. Once you parse modify the data as you wish
3. Use the same library Jackson or Gson to write(serialize) a new JSON document.
4. Jackson may also produce as output XML, YAML and CSV documents

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to have some java code if possible for guidance. If you can have any idea/ Please let me know